# Multi Output Regressor Random Forest - Every output looks at different features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am supposed to predict a hourly timeseries `T` 48 hours ahead in the feature. For technical reasons, I can only use a Random Forest Regressor, with 48 output representing each `T` value `n`hours ahead. There is a big correlation between weather and target output, and therefore as features I include 48 hours ahead weather forecast.

My question is how do I prevent target `T5HoursAhead` from looking at feature `TemperatureAhead25` as doing so is irrelevant, slows down training and probably worsen the results.

Comment: The conceptually simplest way may be to train 48 different RFs, one for each horizon, and feeding each only the data up to that time point.

Comment: That said, there is nothing wrong with feeding your model the weather forecast (!) for two days ahead even if you want to predict your series only for six hours ahead. It may well have predictive power! (E.g., people may buy steak *in anticipation* of good BBQ weather, even if the weather *right now* is bad.) Are you sure these forecasts are irrelevant and will make results worse? I wouldn't be. And simply including these forecasts will certainly be faster than training 48 different models as per my suggestion above.

Comment: Hello Stephan, I think you misunderstood me. I'm not saying that putting temperature forecast is data leakage. I have 700 lines of data (2 years worth of data) and having 48 temperature forecasts is a lot considering the training size. I agree with you that the best idea is to train 48 different RFs but sadly as I'm supposed to productionize, this is not a solution

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are concerned about possible overfitting. That is a valid concern. However, Random Forests are typically not very prone to overfitting. Next, if you have only 700 data points, then training 48 different RFs on that should typically not be a big deal in terms of training time, so I assume your requirement of having only one model has some other rationale. I'm afraid you may need to dig very deeply into scikit-learn to prune your RFs in precisely the way you want. ...

Comment: ... I kind of wonder whether it's really worth it. I would recommend that you try fitting your 48 models in a test environment. Then fit one models with all 48 forecasts. Finally, fit a model with only a small subset of your weather forecasts, maybe four different forecasts 12, 24, 26 and 48 hours out. Then compare these models - in terms of training time and holdout error. Only if the first two model(s) significantly outperform the simple last one in terms of error (and underperform in terms of longer training time) would I invest in potentially having to tweak the scikit-learn code.

Comment: You're right I'm gonna do some testing before going any further. Thanks for your input